# Check the orthogonality of two functions

Tags: inner-products, signal-processing

This is a part of two Passband Signals. My question involves inner product. Is
$$
\left < \cos(2\pi ft + \phi) , \sin(2\pi ft + \phi) \right>
$$
where $\phi \in [-\pi, \pi)$
equal to zero, i.e. that functions are orthogonal? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Kaster: Thank you for editing.

Comment: Which inner product are you using?

Comment: @DennisGulko: imagine <u,v>, so the inner product will be the result of integrating from -infinite to infinite the product of (u)(v*)

Comment: You have to integrate over 1 period, not from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: @Matt: Ok, i see what you are saying. But, as I said at the top of my question this i just a part of the signal. This is the whole question: Let the pulse shape g be a real integrable signal that is bandlimited to W/2 Hz, and let the carrier frequency fc be larger than W/2. Show that, even if the time shifts of g by integer multiples of Ts are not orthonormal, the signals
t→g(t−lTs)cos(2πfct+φ) and t→g(t−l′Ts)sin(2πfct+φ)
are orthogonal for all integers l, l′ (not necessarily distinct). Here φ ∈ [−π, π) is arbitrary.

Comment: So, after a couple of lines, i got that, in order to prove it i must show that ⟨cos(2πft+ϕ),sin(2πft+ϕ)⟩ equals zero. Is it right?

Comment: That's right. Hope you can see it. There should be lots of resources on the internet about it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are orthogonal. Consider the interval $[0,T]$ with $T=1/f$ and integrate, then you'll see it. In this case the inner product is defined by

$$\int_{0}^T \sin\left(\frac{2\pi t}{T}+\phi\right)
\cos\left(\frac{2\pi t}{T}+\phi\right)dt$$

Comment: That's true. But my question is if that inner product equals zero for any value of ϕ when ϕ∈[−π,π)

Comment: The value of $\phi$ doesn't matter as long as it shifts both function values equally. You always integrate over one period $T$, and it doesn't matter where you start.